# vscode removendo imports quando salvo arquivo

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

Tenho um código bem simples em `GO`. Usando o vs code, quando salvo o arquivo que estou trabalhando, o editor remove o `import "math"`

Segue o código

```
package main

import "math"

func main() {
    a := Sqrt(float64(60))
}
```

Quando salvo o arquivo, o formatador do vs code para a linguagem `GO` esta removendo o `import math`, porém ele esta sendo usado (na função Sqrt).

Por que isso esta ocorrendo? É um erro no código ou preciso configurar alguma coisa no vs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é O VS code que remove o import e sim o compilador do GO, em teoria o GO remove todos os importes que você não esteja utilizando por questões de performance.

Quando você faz uma importação de uma biblioteca, você tem que informar que estará utilizando a mesma.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
         //bem aqui utilizando a biblioteca FMT
    a := fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Descobri como resolver o problema, estava faltando o prefixo `math` na frente da função `Sqrt`. Enfim, problemas de iniciante na linguagem.

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
package main

import "math"

func main() {
    a := math.Sqrt(float64(60)) 
}
```